# Dynamic object key at pug (jade) template in JavaScript node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, pug

I have object `sumPrice` on my view and i want to display value depend of key. But the key must be the same as the actual value of the `grp`.

I'll explain better below

```
  - each grp in Object.keys(groupedData)
               h3= grp // for example grp has value Fruit
               table
                  thead
                    th Name
                    th Price
                  tfoot
                    th Sum:
                    th= sumPrice.grp //this doesn't work, but this:  th= sumPrice.Fruit  will work!
                    th
                    th 
                  tbody
                    // [........]
```

I suppose in case `sumPrice.grp`, application searching value for "sumPrice.grp" instead "sumPrice.Fruit" - does not recognize that a grp is variable. Is there any simple solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sumPrice.grp` does not work because `sumPrice` does not have a key named `grp`.

You can do it by using `sumPrice[grp]`.

In this case, you're going to be using the value of `grp` and not it's name.